# Is there some function in $C^1(U)$ but not $W^{1,p}(U)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $U\subset \Bbb{R}^n$ be the bounded domain.

Is there some example such that $f\in C^1(U)$ but not $W^{1,p}(U)$.We know for bounded $U$ we have $$C^1(\overline{U})\subset W^{1,p}(U)$$

Intuitivly the compact set give above is used to prevent the "blowing up" of $f$ near boundary,is there some concrete example for example in 1-dimension?

Comment: Any non integrable $C^1$ function is an counterexample

Comment: $\frac{1}{x}$ is in $C^1(U)$ but not $L^1(U)$ (and hence not in $W^{1,1}$), for $U=(0,1)$

Comment: oh thanks I have considered the $1/x$ but forget to restrict it into bounded region

Comment: a similar example consider $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{(x+1)(x-1)}$ over $(-1,1)$